# Object of class WP_Query could not be converted to int inside shortcode

Tags: wp-query, shortcode, advanced-custom-fields, advanced-taxonomy-queries, wp-error

I have the following code which is used to display download posts by the custom taxonomy. I am receiving the error

> Object of class WP_Query could not be converted to int

When I have Query Monitor enabled but I am struggling to work out exactly which bit is causing it as the actual code works and displays the correct files in the correct groupings.

I am wondering if it needs to be simplified somehow but if anyone can help me spot the problem I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance

```
function downloads_shortcode( $atts ) {

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'type' => 'assoc-downloads',
    'posts' => -1,
    'download_type' => '',
    'category' => '',
    'post_id' => '',
), $atts));


$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $type ); ?>
<article class="page type-page status-publish entry"><?php
foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) :

    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, array ('order' => 'DESC', 'orderby' =>'title'));

    foreach( $terms as $term ) :
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => $type,
                    'posts_per_page' => $posts,  //show all posts
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'download_type' => $download_type,
                    'category_name' => $category,
                    'post_id' => $post_id,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $term->slug,
                        )
                    )
                );
                $posts = new WP_Query($args);

                if( $posts->have_posts() ): while( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();

                    $attachment_id = get_field('document');
                    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
                    $title = get_the_title();
                    // part where to get the filesize
                    $filesize = filesize( get_attached_file( $attachment_id ) );
                    $filesize = size_format($filesize, 2); ?>

                    <section class="category-section">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="span12">
                                <h1 class="mid-heading"><?php echo $term->name; ?></h1>
                            </div>

                    <?php echo '<div class="ecd-single"><p><i style="font-size:120%; margin: 0px 6px 0px 3px;opacity:0.5" class="fa fa-file"></i><a href="'.$url.'" title="'.$title.'" class="ecd-download-file">' .$title.' </a> ('.$filesize.') <i  style="font-size:120%; margin: 2px 0 0 5px;opacity:0.5" class="fa fa-download"></i> <a href="'.$url.'">Download</a></p></div></div></section>';
                endwhile; endif;
    endforeach;
endforeach;
echo '</article>';}
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote the function based on a few other posts I have seen online and now have the following code which works without any errors.

I am still open to any further suggestions on the best way to streamline this code even further it it can be.

Thanks again

```
function downloads_shortcode($atts){

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'download_type' => ''
), $atts));

// get the terms
$terms = get_terms( 'download_type' );

// no terms?  bail.
if( ! $terms ) return '';

$out = '';

// loop through the terms
foreach( $terms as $term )
{
    // get videos in each term
    $downloads = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'assoc-downloads',
        'download_type' => $download_type,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'download_type',
                'field'     => 'id',
                'terms'     => $term->term_id,
                'operator'  => 'IN'
            )
        )
    ));

    // no downloads? continue!
    if( ! $downloads ) continue;

    $out .= '<h2>' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</h2>';
    $out .= '<ul>';
    // loop through the download posts
    foreach( $downloads as $d )
    {
        $attachment_id = get_field('document', $d);
        $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
        $title = get_the_title($d);
        // part where to get the filesize
        $filesize = filesize( get_attached_file( $attachment_id, $d ) );
        $filesize = size_format($filesize, 2);

        $out .= '<div class="ecd-single"><p><i style="font-size:120%; margin: 0px 6px 0px 3px;opacity:0.5" class="fa fa-file"></i><a href="'.$url.'" title="'.$title.'" class="ecd-download-file">' .$title.' </a> ('.$filesize.') <i  style="font-size:120%; margin: 2px 0 0 5px;opacity:0.5" class="fa fa-download"></i> <a href="'.$url.'">Download</a></p></div>';
    }
    $out .= '</ul>';
}
return $out;}
```

Comment: This also works for just showing a specific category using the download_type option in the shortcode. Would be great to find out the best way to also have an ID option for the shortcode to just show a specific download result. Currently I have another shortcode to do this.